# How do I create an alias where the arguments go in the middle?

Tags: bash, unix, shell, alias, sh

I'm trying to define an alias where the arguments are inserted in the middle, instead of appended to the end.

I tried defining it like this:

```
alias grep_logs="grep $1 */log/*.log"
```

where $1 is the first argument to grep_logs, such that:

```
grep_logs foo
```

would execute the following command:

```
grep foo */log/*.log
```

but instead, it runs the command:

```
grep foo */log/*.log foo
```

which results in the error:

```
grep: foo: No such file or directory
```

Is it possible to do this using an alias or do I need to define a function?

Comment: Could make a super simple python script to automate it, have you tried it? (hint: you would have to make use of sys.argv)

Comment: Instead of an alias, write a function.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try defining a function in ~/.profile.

```
function greplogs(){
    grep "$1" */logs/*.log
}
```

Comment: If you want to pass multiple arguments, you can use `${@:1}` instead of `"$1"` and it will insert all arguments there. Might be useful for someone who needs _an alias with arguments in the middle_.

Comment: Just to note, you don't need to use `function`, you can just start with `greplogs() {`. Also, if you do use `function` it will break in ksh.

Comment: How to call the function passing the argument?

Comment: @Pijusn Why not `$@`? Although clearly `${@:2}` is useful for skipping the first argument.

Comment: @piojo you are right they are equal (AFAIK). Not sure why I didn't just suggest `$@`. :)

Comment: `function` is legal ksh syntax, but not with `()` -- you can use `function greplogs {` legally in legacy ksh; by contrast, with POSIX sh, only `greplogs() {` is legal, and `function` is not.

Comment: @Eduard, just `greplogs "thing-to-grep-for"`, the same way one passes arguments to any other shell comand.

Answer (score 23):

Just for the sake of answering the question, although the function solution is much cleaner:

```
alias sstatus='bash -xc '\''sudo service $0 status'\'''
alias sstart='bash -xc '\''sudo service $0 start'\'''
alias sstop='bash -xc '\''sudo service $0 stop'\'''


$sstatus cups
+ sudo service cups status
Status of Common Unix Printing System: cupsd is running.
```

Answer (score 16):

Expanding upon [@erjoalgo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27882274/5353461) which so far is the only one which actually answers the question:

##`alias` arguments
Shell aliases *do* accept arguments, but only at the *end*:

```
$ alias speak=echo
$ speak hello world
hello world
```

Putting arguments into the *middle* of command via `alias` is indeed possible but it gets ugly.

### Don't try this at home, kiddies!

If you like circumventing limitations and doing what others say is impossible, here's the recipe. Just don't blame me if your hair gets frazzled and your face ends up covered in soot mad-scientist-style.

The workaround is to pass the arguments that `alias` accepts only at the end to a wrapper that will insert them in the middle and then execute your command.

###Solution 1

If you're really against using a function per se, you can use:

```
$ alias wrap_args='f(){ echo before "$@" after;  unset -f f; }; f'
$ wrap_args x y z
before x y z after
```

You can replace `$@` with `$1` if you only want the first argument.

**Explanation 1**

This creates a temporary function `f`, which is passed the arguments (note that `f` is called at the very end). The `unset -f` removes the function definition as the alias is executed so it doesn't hang around afterwards.

###Solution 2

You can also use a subshell:

```
$ alias wrap_args='sh -c '\''echo before "$@" after'\'' _'
```

**Explanation 2**

The alias builds a command like:

```
sh -c 'echo before "$@" after' _
```

Comments:

- The placeholder `_` is required, but it could be anything. It gets set to `sh`'s `$0`, and is required so that the first of the user-given arguments don't get consumed. Demonstration:

  ```
   sh -c 'echo Consumed: "$0" Printing: "$@"' alcohol drunken babble
   Consumed: alcohol Printing: drunken babble
  ```
- The double-quotes inside single-quotes are required. Here's an example of it not working with double quotes:

  ```
   $ sh -c "echo Consumed: $0 Printing: $@" alcohol drunken babble
   Consumed: -bash Printing:
  ```

  Here the values of the interactive shell's `$0` and `$@` are replaced into the double quoted *before* it is passed to `sh`. Here's proof:

  ```
   echo "Consumed: $0 Printing: $@"
   Consumed: -bash Printing:
  ```

  The single quotes ensure that these variables are not interpreted by interactive shell, and are passed literally to `sh -c`.

  You could use double-quotes and `\$@`, but best practice is to quote your arguments (as they may contain spaces), and `\"\$@\"` looks even uglier, but may help you win an obfuscation contest where frazzled hair is a prerequisite for entry.

Answer (score 4):

Not quite the answer you're looking for but use the `-e` argument if don't want to specify the pattern as the first argument

```
alias grep_logs="grep */log/*.log -e"
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that aliases don't support the concept of *positional parameters*. If they did, we wouldn't need functions. So yes, use a function because functions are made exactly for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Try using a function and then aliasing it:

```
function func_grep_logs {
    grep $1 */log/*.log
}
```

then

```
alias grep_logs="func_grep_logs"
```

Comment: why not `grep "$1" */log/*.log`?

Comment: What exactly is the benefit of the alias then? The right answer is that an alias is the wrong answer, and a function is the way to go instead.

Comment: no () after function name in declaration?